# pandas dataframe extract strings

Tags: numpy, pandas, dataframe, text-extraction

My data frame has a column called 'a' and it may contain 'apple' and 'orange'. What I want is to extract them if they exist, otherwise label 'others'.

I can simply loop over the rows and extract them. However, I saw some usage of `numpy.where()` for similar purposes, but only two categories.

```
result = numpy.where(df['a'].str.contains('apple'), 'apple', 'others')
```

Is it possible to apply it here for the case of 3 categories? In other words, `result` should contain entries of 'apple', 'orange', or 'others'.

Is there some better way to do it than simply looping?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) with [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['orange','apple','a']})
print (df)
        a
0  orange
1   apple
2       a

df['new'] = df.a.str.extract('(orange|apple)', expand=False).fillna('others')
print (df)
        a     new
0  orange  orange
1   apple   apple
2       a  others
```

Comment: I want the result to be one of the 3 possibilities: 'apple', 'orange' or 'others'.

Answer (score 3):

Simply look for items that are `apple` or `mango` with `np.in1d` to create a boolean mask, which could then be used with `np.where` to set rest of them as `others`. Thus, we would have -

```
df['b'] = np.where(np.in1d(df.a,['apple','orange']),df.a,'others')
```

For cases when you might be looking to work with strings that have those names as part of bigger strings, you can use `str.extract` (caught this idea from [`@jezrael's solution`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38338824/3293881), I hope that's okay!) and then use `np.where`, like so -

```
strings = df.a.str.extract('(orange|apple)')
df['b'] = np.where(np.in1d(strings,['apple','orange']),strings,'others')
```

Sample run -

```
In [294]: df
Out[294]: 
             a
0  apple-shake
1       orange
2  apple-juice
3        apple
4        mango
5       orange
6       banana

In [295]: strings = df.a.str.extract('(orange|apple)')

In [296]: df['b'] = np.where(np.in1d(strings,['apple','orange']),strings,'others')

In [297]: df
Out[297]: 
             a       b
0  apple-shake   apple
1       orange  orange
2  apple-juice   apple
3        apple   apple
4        mango  others
5       orange  orange
6       banana  others
```